# Azure B2C Single Sign on working with IIS Express but not with Local IIS

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have two MVC applications using Azure B2C. I have added these two applications to B2C portal. When I use IIS Express, I can log in to one app, and when I refresh the other app, it automatically logs me in. When I use Local IIS, when I log into one app, I refresh the other app, it still thinks that I am not logged in (Request.IsAuthenticated is false). When I log in to the other app, and I refresh my first app, Request.IsAuthenticated is returned as false. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Generally, single sign-on is tied to a cookie which is specific to a domain. Is there any chance your two websites in IIS have different domains? Or maybe the cookies are getting blown away in IIS in between running your two websites? Can you check if the cookies are the same across in IIS Express and IIS?

Comment: I had to set the machine key and the decryption key same for all the applications using SSO (instead of letting IIS generate a key runtime). Once I did this, SSO works.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the machine key and the decryption key same for all the applications using SSO (instead of letting IIS generate a key runtime). Once I did this, SSO works.